# How do I create a custom DVD player for XBox?

Tags: xna, xbox360, dvd

I would like to create an application that runs on XBox 360 (downloaded using XBox Live) that will play the DVD movie in the tray.  I know the XBox already has this ability, but I want my custom DVD player to allow users to save bookmarks for parts of the movie they really like and then browse their bookmarks later when they put the DVD back in.  It might sound silly, but it is for a business venture I am undertaking.

My questions are:
1. Is this possible?
2. What platform can I use to make this? (XNA?)
3. Where should I go to learn how to do it?

I am a very experienced .NET developer but I am not an expert in media or game programming (yet).  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make an official agreement with Microsoft, because XNA Community Games are the only homemade applications that can be downloaded via Xbox Live and there is no public API for accessing the DVD-playing capabilities of the 360.